# What type of widget to use which lets the user upload an Excel file to a Flutter app?

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I am fairly new to Flutter, and want to know which widget-type would be the most appropriate to use which lets each user upload an Excel file (data parsing takes place on the back-end). The Input Wigdets documentation on Flutter website shows only text-based input field widgets, so I don't know which one to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [file picker](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/file_picker) package. Makes it much easier and straightforward.

If you have any issue using it, just mention and I'll be glad to help you out. 
Welcome to Flutter, It's awesome